# Pandas: Convert multi-index level to a new set of columns

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, data-analysis

I have seen people take a bunch of column names and turn them into a lower level within the multi-index for each row, but how would you undo that?

I have a multi-index of a Series and I want to convert one level's index names into columns. I'm trying to avoid creating a new DataFrame and iterating through each value of the index.

```
matrix = df.groupby([B, A]).count().amount
print(matrix)
```

produces

```
method          company
Direct Deposit  A             2
                B            13
                E           161
                F          4423
Paper Check     A            40
                C            12
                D           523
                E            50
eCheck          A            27
                B            13
                C            22
                D           967
                E           222
                F          1835
```

I tried the `matrix.to_frame(index=True)` but got this

```
                                method company
method         company                        
Direct Deposit A        Direct Deposit       A
               B        Direct Deposit       B
               E        Direct Deposit       E
               F        Direct Deposit       F
Paper Check    A           Paper Check       A
               C           Paper Check       C
               D           Paper Check       D
               E           Paper Check       E
eCheck         A                eCheck       A
               B                eCheck       B
               C                eCheck       C
               D                eCheck       D
               E                eCheck       E
               F                eCheck       F
```

**Desired**

```
     company    A       B       C       D       E       F
method
Direct Deposit  2       13      0       0       161     4423
Paper Check     40      0       12      523     50      0
eCheck          27      13      22      967     222     1835
```

Comment: how about `matrix.unstack()`?

Comment: Oh wow didn't know about that method. Solved it perfectly, thank you!